# What is the difference between == "" and is empty

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am learning AMP Script.

Can someone please explain the difference between the if empty(@) and if @ == " " in AMP Script please?

I have tested both examples below to only show the HTML content block when a field value is empty/blank or equals to blank. The first example if @ == " " works and the second example doesn't.

The problem is that I have used if @(empty) in other ampscript blocks and the code works as expected. I am not able to understand the reason behind this and why it won't work in this example. Is it because I am looking against another data extension?

(Apologies if the below lookup is also incorrect - as I don't fully understand and trying to read up as I go)

Example 1:

```
%%[
    /* Adding business invite logic */
    VAR @account
    SET @account =  Lookup("customer info", "account_status", "customer_id", @account)
]%%
%%[IF @account == "" THEN]%%
<------SHOW this HTML block if it is empty------>
%%[ENDIF]%%
```

and....

Example 2:

```
%%[
    /* Adding business invite logic */
    VAR @account
    SET @account =  Lookup("customer info", "account_status", "customer_id", @account)
]%%
%%[IF empty(@account) THEN]%%
<------SHOW this HTML block if it is empty------>
%%[ENDIF]%%
```

Here is an example of another ampscript block outside of this where EMPTY works.

```
  <p>Thank you for your recent enquiry.</p>
%%[ if not empty (@order_reference_number) then ]%%
<p>Order Number: %%=v(@order_reference_number)=%%</p>
%%[ endif ]%%
  <p>Please see a copy of your transcript below:</p>
```

Comment: If == "" would represent that your wallet has no money; Empty() would be that you don't have a wallet. 

EMPTY() evaluates NULL, == "" evaluates empty strings. 

You saying EMPTY works but not == "" implies (to me at least) that the account_status column never had a value, nor has been targeted with via an import or query. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16620354/difference-between-null-and-empty-string

Comment: Thank you, that is helping. The == " " worked but EMPTY didn't. I assumed it is because I am looking against another data extension. I have also updated the Q above where the EMPTY has worked in another ampscript block outside of these examples but here I believe I am sending order reference number in my payload as {"order_reference_number" : ""} - and this is probably why it is working?

Comment: If you're saying {"order_reference_number" : ""} works when using == "", that makes sense. The node is passing something - it's passing nothing (empty wallet). If your payload didn't include order_reference_number at all, the row it would write to would leave the targeted NULL (what wallet?).

Comment: Hmm, no the {"order_reference_number" : ""} works when I also use if %%[ if not empty @ ]%%